# Yii - updating fields within CListView

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to update individual fields within CListView? I am looking for a solution that lets users edit their records in this view of all table records.

An example would be where a user has a list of associated appointments. They might want to quickly mark an appointment as priority low/high without going to the update view itself.

Are there widgets other than CListView for this sort of function?

Sorry, I ran into a bit of a dead end researching this, I may have missed something *blindingly* obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There is no miracle solution, it will depend on the task you want to accomplish;

if you want to have buttons to change task priority, you can use ajax link (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail).

if you want to edit text inline, you can use a combination of Jeditable (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and some ajax to edit the text, then update the content of the item.

By the way, just a quick reminder that you can partially render a view to a string (a PHP variable, that is) with the [renderPartial method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail).  So you could render only the updated CListView item and return it to the ajax callback to update the content.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Let say below is your list view

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'id'=>'itemList',

)); ?>
```

and your partial (_view.php)

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Mark Status',array('appointment/update','id'=>$data->id),
                array('type'=>'POST','success'=>'function(){loadListView()}'),
                array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to mark complete this appointment?',
                    'id'=>'mark-'.$data->id));  ?>
```

The function for reloading all of grid (not individual field) since maybe the updated record may affect to other data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadListView(){
            $.fn.yiiListView.update('itemList');
        }
    </script>
```

There has some reference could be example for you

http://help.discretelogix.com/php/yii/enable-in-place-editing-in-yii-grid.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can implement,

TbEditableColumn (YiiBooster) or EditableColumn (x-editable for Yii) and edit your date on fly. Only you need implement one of above widgets after create new some update action in related controller receive data from POST request and update data.

[Very usefull related Yii wiki link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/532/get-source-data-from-the-database-for-tbeditablecolumn-or-editablecolumn-type-select-dropdownlist/)